# How to properly write asnprintf without format string compiler warnings?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'd like to write a `asnprintf` function -- which is a wrapper around snprintf, but it mallocs the string according to its output size.  Unfortunately when I compile I get a warning (promoted to error on my system) `format string is not a string literal [-Werror,-Wformat-nonliteral]`.

I looked up the warning and apparently there are security concerns with passing a non-literal to `printf` functions, but in my case, I need to take in a format pointer, and pass that on.

Is there a good way around this that does not expose the same security vulnerability?

My function as is is as follows:

```c
int
asnprintf(char **strp, int max_len, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int len;
    va_list ap,ap2;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
    if ( len > max_len)
        len = max_len;
    *strp = malloc(len+1);
    if (*strp == NULL)
        return -1;
    len = vsnprintf(*strp, len+1, fmt, ap2);
    va_end(ap2);
    va_end(ap);

    return len;
}
```

Comment: You can implement this with `fmemopen` and/or `open_memstream` and do a _single_ `fprintf` instead of reinventing it.

Comment: @CraigEstey either way that wouldn't resolve OP's issue, wince `fprintf` would still need a `fmt` that is not a string literal. OP's implementation is more or less the de-facto standard `asnprintf` implementation, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: This compiles clean for me under gcc 4.8.5.  What compiler/version are you using, and what are the exact arguments you're passing?

Comment: I'm less worried about the warning as the security hole that I have now opened (if I just disable the warning, someone can now use my code to access the vulnerability).   I'm wondering if it's possible for example to require that my function take only string literals, and only then disable the warning...

Comment: This is a great example of why coding standards must have some provision for waivers.

Comment: @dbush it shouldn't with `-Wformat-nonliteral -Werror`

Comment: I'm compiling with clang.11.0-p13 -- options are really long, but include `-Werror` and `-Wformat-nonliteral `

Comment: Interesting that clang puts up a warning for this, considering that you can't check the arguments to the `v*printf` functions at compile time.  The docs for gcc on this option specifically says that these functions are excluded regarding this warning.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I've seen the double `sprintf` impl. I've even used it in an answer here. But, I must not be understanding the impact/purpose of `-Wformat-nonliteral` as doing `v*printf` calls are okay here [AFAICT]. But, with the `v*` versions, you can't check the args in `ap` anyway. Maybe `asnprintf` needs (e.g.) `__attribute__((__format__(__printf__,3,4)))` I've just compiled it semi-cleanly, but I had to change `len = vsnprintf(strp, len + 1, fmt, ap2);` into `len = vsnprintf(*strp, len + 1, fmt, ap2);`

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, with that attribute gcc will warn if `asnprintf` is called with a non-literal format string.

Comment: @dbush ah interesting, did not know about that attribute.

Comment: Your code compiles without warnings for me with GCC 8.5.0, using `Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wformat-nonliteral`, though that's probably more a function of the version of glibc (v2.28 for me) and how that is built than it is of GCC.

Comment: I'd consider this a bug in clang that `-Wformat-literal` warns for `v*printf` functions.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I always add that for my printf-like functions [of which I have a fair amount], so I was confused. I think we want to add the attribute to `asnprintf` but _not_ compile with `-Wformat-nonliteral`. The attribute ensures a literal `fmt` and can check all calls to `asnprintf`. But, there's no need for the `v*printf` to check: (1) `fmt` is already guaranteed to be a literal (2) The `v*printf` _can't_ check (and shouldn't).

Comment: In fact, with the attribute defined, the warning goes away so I don't even have to disable it (clang seems to be smart enough to know that it no longer applies)

Comment: @dbush Do you mean `-Wformat-nonliteral`? I have gcc 8.3.1 and glibc 2.28 and I get the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comments ...

Just add `__attribute__((__format__(__printf__,3,4)))` to your `asnprintf` declaration and/or definition.

This will cue the compiler to *not* complain.

And, the further benefit is that it will check the variadic arguments passed to `asnprintf` against the format string.

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// put this in a .h file!?
int __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,3,4)))
asnprintf(char **strp, int max_len, const char *fmt, ...);

int
asnprintf(char **strp, int max_len, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int len;
    va_list ap, ap2;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    va_copy(ap2, ap);

    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
    if (len > max_len)
        len = max_len;
    *strp = malloc(len + 1);
    if (*strp == NULL)
        return -1;
    len = vsnprintf(*strp, len + 1, fmt, ap2);

    va_end(ap2);
    va_end(ap);

    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting only GCC and Clang as compilers, you can get around this pretty easily by temporarily disabling the warning for that specific function:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security"

// Function definition here...

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Clang should recognize `#pragma GCC` too. You may also need to ignore `-Wformat-security` as I did above depending on your compiler flags.

[Godbolt link to working example with Clang 11](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:51,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:51,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Achar+fmt%5B100%5D%3B%0A%0A%23pragma+GCC+diagnostic+push%0A%23pragma+GCC+diagnostic+ignored+%22-Wformat-nonliteral%22%0A%23pragma+GCC+diagnostic+ignored+%22-Wformat-security%22%0A%0Aint+main(void)+%7B%0A++++printf(fmt)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23pragma+GCC+diagnostic+pop%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.81017612524462,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1101,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-Wformat+-Wformat-nonliteral+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+11.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:42.028985507246375,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+11.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:57.971014492753625,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.18982387475538,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

---

> I'm wondering if it's possible for example to require that my function take only string literals

[As Craig Estey suggests above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465782/how-to-properly-write-asnprintf-without-format-string-compiler-warnings/74465914#comment131453941_74465782), you could make use of the `format` function attribute to make the compiler perform this check for you:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security"

int __attribute__((format(printf, 3, 4))) asnprintf(char **strp, int max_len, const char *fmt, ...) {
    // ... implementation ...
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

char global_fmt[100];

int main(void) {
    char *res;

    asnprintf(&res, 100, "asd");         // will compile
    asnprintf(&res, 100, global_fmt);    // will NOT compile
    return 0;
}
```

You could also do this, with a bit of trickery, using a macro and some compiler built-ins:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security"

int internal_asnprintf(char **strp, int max_len, const char *fmt, ...) {
    return printf(fmt);
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

#define asnprintf(strp, maxlen, fmt, ...) ({ \
    _Static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(fmt), "format string is not a constant"); \
    internal_asnprintf(strp, maxlen, fmt, __VA_ARGS__); \
})

char global_fmt[100];

int main(void) {
    char *res;

    asnprintf(&res, 100, "asd");         // will compile
    asnprintf(&res, 100, global_fmt);    // will NOT compile
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above code makes use of statement expressions (`({...})`) which are a non-standard extension and may or may not be available depending on your compiler flags.